# xcode project export error

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, nsrangeexception

I have this problem: I sent to a friend my xcode project, he is able to open and run without errors, but at some point the app crashes.
More precisely app manages a sqlite database that stores the scores of the game and just when he tries to enter the page that shows the scores the app crashes with a `NSRangeException` as the data structure that stores the scores extracted from the db is empty.

Of course in my Xcode it works perfectly so, is there anything special I need to do before exporting a project to make it work on another mac? Should I also add the db file and make him re-import into his project?
I just created a zip file with the project folder.
If anyone can help me would be greatly appreciated. Thank you